# Testing for multiple exceptions with JUnit 4 annotations

Tags: java, junit, exception

Is it possible to test for multiple exceptions in a single JUnit unit test?  I know for a single exception one can use, for example

```
    @Test(expected=IllegalStateException.class)
```

Now, if I want to test for another exception (say, NullPointerException), can this be done in the same annotation, a different annotation or do I need to write another unit test completely?

Comment: If more than one exception indicates that the tested code works as expected, then the test isn't well defined. You should expect exactly one thing from a test.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You really want the test to do *one* thing, and to test for that. If you're not sure as to which exception is going to be thrown, that doesn't sound like a good test to me.

e.g. (in pseudo-code)

```
try {
   badOperation();
   /// looks like we succeeded. Not good! Fail the test
   fail();
}
catch (ExpectedException e) {
   // that's fine
}
catch (UnexpectedException e) {
   // that's NOT fine. Fail the test
}
```

so if you want to test that your method throws 2 different exceptions (for 2 sets of inputs), then you'll need 2 tests.

Comment: I usually call fail() within the try block, immediately after badOperation().

Comment: At any given point I am sure which statement I expect to throw an error. In one test, I wish to test that all expected exceptions gets thrown. I'll be honest, I'm not thrilled about the annotation way of testing for exceptions: a bad test may cause an expected exception at an unexpected point in the test. In that sense I favour the try-catch-fail of testing for an exception, but just looks ugly. I suppose you are right in a sense, though: my tests should be more atomic (rather than testing everything for one method in a single unit test, as I am trying to do).

Comment: @Yuval - I was trying to be test-framework agnostic in the above. However I've amended to be clearer.

Comment: @Phantom - atomicity for tests can be a pain, but I believe that's the way forward, and reduces ambiguity when your tests fail.  I have written tests that check for multiple exceptions though by not using annotations and nesting tests within the catch blocks of preceeding tests. After a while it gets a bug ugly...

Comment: The "catch (UnexpectedOperation e)" is unnecessary; if a test method throws an exception, that's considered a failure. As Yuval mentioned, you need to do a fail() immediately after badOperation()

Comment: @NamshubWriter - you're missing the point. The above is pseudo-code illustrating when you need to take action.

Answer (score 13):

This is not possible with the annotation.

With JUnit 4.7 you can use the new `ExpectedException` rule

```
public static class HasExpectedException {
    @Interceptor
    public ExpectedException thrown= new ExpectedException();

    @Test
    public void throwsNothing() {
    }

    @Test
    public void throwsNullPointerException() {
         thrown.expect(NullPointerException.class);
         throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    @Test
    public void throwsNullPointerExceptionWithMessage() {
        thrown.expect(NullPointerException.class);
        thrown.expectMessage("happened?");
        throw new NullPointerException("What happened?");
    }
}
```

More see

- [JUnit 4.7: Interceptors: expected exceptions](http://greenbar.saff.net/?p=17)
- [Rules in JUnit 4.7](http://greenbar.saff.net/?p=18)

---

If updating to JUnit 4.7 is not possible for you, you have to write a bare unit test of the form

```
public test() {
    try {
        methodCall(); // should throw Exception
        fail();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        assert((ex instanceof A) || (ex instanceof B) || ...etc...);
        ...
    }
```

}

Comment: I had a case where I had to test for one of a list of Exception classes. If you use an @Nonnull annotation in your code, a unit test run from the IDE may throw an InvalidArgumentException, but if you run the test from a build (i.e. maven, gradle), you still have to test for null and could respond with another type of exception. The following catches both cases:
`expected.expect(CoreMatchers.anyOf(CoreMatchers.instanceOf(IllegalArgumentException.class), CoreMatchers.instanceOf(MyCustomInvalidFieldValueException.class)));`

Answer (score 6):

Although this is not possible with JUnit 4, it *is* possible if you switch to TestNG, which allows you to write

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = {IllegalArgumentException.class, NullPointerException.class})
```

Comment: Did not know this.  Cool.

Answer (score 3):

Use [catch-exception](http://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/):

```
// test 
public void testDo() {

   // obj.do(1) must throw either A or B
   catchException(obj).do(1);
   assert caughtException() instanceof A
       || caughtException() instanceof B;

   // obj.do(2) must throw A but not SubclassOfA
   catchException(obj).do(2);
   assert caughtException() instanceof A
       && !(caughtException() instanceof SubclassOfA);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Test(expected=Exception.class)
```

This will throw all possible exceptions.

Comment: it expects all exceptions not throw them.

Answer (score 1):

How would you expect to "expected"s to work? A method can only throw one exception.

You would have to write a different unit test for each way the method can fail. So if the method legitimately throw two exceptions then you need two tests set up to force the method of throwing each exception.

Comment: A method can only throw one exception, but can be declared as throwing many different exceptions.  Say that a method can throw 4 exception types, throwing either A or B passes the test, throwing C or D fails the test.  This would be easy is 'expected' tool an array of classes instead of a single class

Comment: But under one set of data is can only fail in one way.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the tests as simple and short as possible. The intention of a JUnit-Test is to test only one simple functionality or one single way of failure.

Indeed, to be safe, you should create at least one test for every possible execution way.

Normally, this is not always possible because if you have a method that analyses a string, there are so many possible string combinations that you cannot cover everything.

Keep it short and simple.

You can have 30-40 testing methods for one single method easily... does it really matter?

Regards